# Infinite Simple Groups

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

I have been reading about the [Rado Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado_graph) (or Random graph), which we will call $R$, and had a question regarding its automorphism group, $\operatorname{Aut}(R)$. In a paper that I am reading, it states that $\operatorname{Aut}(R)$ is simple but it omits the proof. Instead the author gives a citation for the following fact:

> if any $g,h \in \operatorname{Aut}(R)$ are non-identity elements, then
>   $h$ can be expressed as a product of five conjugates of $g$ or
>   $g^{-1}$,

and then parenthetically says (clearly this implies simplicity). However this is not too clear to me. What little knowledge I have a simple groups is almost all in regards to finite groups. Could someone explain how simplicity follows from the fact above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $N\le Aut(R)$ were normal and contained a nonidentity element $g$. Then every conjugate of $g$ and $g^{-1}$ is contained in $N$, since $N$ is normal. But since $N$ is closed under the group operation, any other non-identity $h$ is also contained in $N$. So $N= Aut(R)$.

Comment: Ahhh, so the condition about being the product of five conjugates is just kind of a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

The statements says any element is  a product of 5 conjugates of any non-identity element  $g$ or $g^{-1}$. So if $g$ were in a normal subgroup, then all its conjugates can generate any element of $G$. But by normality these have to be in that normal subgroup. So whole of $G$ is in any non trivial normal subgroup. That is, the group is simple.